# How to enable docker-compose when connecting to a docker-machine via ssh?

Tags: docker

I'm having some problems to setup the shared folder in the docker machine. I'm using Windows and when I tried run the mount command in the Docker Quickstart Terminal I've got this error:

```
mount: unknown option -- t
Try `mount --help' for more information.
```

I also don't have permissions to create folders or to run sudo.

I found this article http://blog.pavelsklenar.com/5-useful-docker-tip-and-tricks-on-windows/ and by using Putty, I have managed to run the command but now I have another problem: I'm using docker-compose to build and run my containers but docker-compose is available when connecting using Putty only when using Docker Quickstart Terminal.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by installing docker-compose through the ssh connection
https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/